# Не получается правильно совместить две строки

Tags: javascript

Задание с CodeWars:

> Возьмите две строки, содержащие только буквы от "a" до "z", и верните
> новую строку, максимально длинную, состоящую из различных букв.
>
> - Каждая буква должна быть взята только один раз исходя из двух строк. Буквы должны располагаться в алфавитном порядке

Я попытался сделать это задание при помощи двух циклов, но у меня, к сожалению, не получается пройти с ними все испытания. Объясните, пожалуйста, что не так в моём решении.

```
function longest(s1, s2) {
    let result = s1 + s2,
        answer,
         array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (result[i] == array[j]) {
                answer = "";
                break;
            } else if (result[i] != array[j]) {
                answer = result[i];
            }
        }
        array.push(answer);
    }
    return array.sort().join("");
};
```

Мне известны входные данные только удачных испытаний:

```
console.log(longest("aretheyhere", "yestheyarehere"));
```

Я не могу узнать входные данные проваленных испытаний. Но вот ссылка на задание: https://www.codewars.com/kata/two-to-one/train/javascript

Comment: Положить обе строки посимвольно в массив типа `Set`. Далее преобразовать в обычный, отсортировать. Склеить обратно через join().

Answer (score 3):

```js
const a = 'aretheyhere';
const b = 'yestheyarehere';

const result = [...new Set(a+b)].sort().join('');
console.log(result);
```